# Multiplication of Matrix cyclic diagonals

Tags: matrices

Given $n\times n$ matrices, $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$ and $B=(b_{i,j})_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$ such that $a_{i,j}\neq 0$ for $i-j=k$ or $k-n$ and $b_{i,j}\neq 0$ for $i-j=l$ or $l-n$ , where, $k,l=1,2,\cdots n-1$ then show  that $(AB)_{i,j}\neq 0$ for $i-j=k+l$ or $k+l-n$.\

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question requires some precision. First when you wrote $k,l=1,2,\cdots n-1$, are you sure that it is not $k,l \in \{1,2,\cdots n-1\}$? Second you mention when coefficients of matrices $A$ and $B$ are not vanishing. **What about the other coefficients?**

Comment: I am writing question in another way. We denote by $D_k$ the set of all matrices of the form $A(a_{i,j})_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$ , such that $a_{i,j}\neq 0$ for $i-j=k$ or $k-n$, and  $k=1,2,\cdots n-1$. Then we have to show that if $A\in D_k$ and $B\in D_l$ then $AB\in D_{k+l}$ whenver k+l\leq n-1. Regarding your question we have $a_i,j=0$ for $i-j\neq k$ or $k-n$.  I hope question is clear now.